# Need Date Calculation MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, formula

I need a flexible table that displays dates. By flexible, I mean, if I put in June 15, 1976, it displays as such. But if I put 20, Access calculates that 20 in the same field as today's date - 20 years.

I set the formatting of the date/time field in table: tbl_ageLimit to #, so it displays a serial date rather than a user readable date. This table has one field: ageLimit.

I am trying to develop a query to recognize if the date is not relevant in its current state and then convert it to something relevant and put it in another table that will constantly update.

Right now, I'm just trying to get formula to work on recognizing and converting the date. This is the formula that works splendidly in excel, but doesn't seem to be working in MS Access:

```
IIF([ageLimit]<=100,Date()-365*[ageLimit],[ageLimit])
```

It recognizes if the field has a number in it that is less than 100. But it's not doing the math and displaying a new record in the new table. Below is the sql:

```
SELECT tbl_ageLimit.ageLimit INTO tbl_allAges
FROM tbl_ageLimit
WHERE (((tbl_ageLimit.ageLimit)=IIf([ageLimit]<=100,Date()-365*[ageLimit],[ageLimit])));
```

Can someone kindly point out to me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

As requested, here are snapshots of the problem:

[image: tbl_ageLimit Time/Date Field formatted as serial date][image: tbl_allAges showing four records instead of five. Where's the fifth record?]

The table that is created is not showing the fifth record. Stumped.

Comment: How does that formula work splendidly in Excel? Excel does not use `IIF()`. *But it's not doing the math*...please show us some data of current and desired result.

Comment: It's also quite alright to tell me my design is flawed. The purpose is because different states have different laws on lending on certain properties. Unfortunately, some say 20 years old, others have a firm date, such as June 15, 1976. Others just have a year.

Comment: Excel does have an IIf() formula, it's just IF(expression,if true, if false).

Comment: Correct. `IF()` (a Worksheet function) is NOT `IIF()` (an SQL method available in Expressions). In fact, Excel's `OR()` and `AND()` are functions not logical operators as in SQL. This is not splitting hairs as semantics and syntax is very important in programming.

Comment: Right, I get that. I'm not a programmer. I do my best nonetheless. But shouldn't it show a date, as I ran it through a calculation if a number was less than 100. Shouldn't it take that 20, multiply it by 365 and then subtract that product from today's date?

Comment: No, ageLimit is a Date/Time field, formatted to give me the serial date. (Format #)

Comment: ageLimit in the second table is being created by the query, and is also a Date/Time Field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider removing the `WHERE` clause as you do not need to filter records. Since you intend to evaluate the `IIF()` expression, place in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT IIf([ageLimit]<=100, Date()-365*[ageLimit], [ageLimit]) As [age_Limit]
INTO tbl_allAges
FROM tbl_ageLimit
```

Comment: It's giving me a circular reference dialogue box. Maybe an Access limitation?

Comment: Rename the table alias. See update with [age_Limit]. Then rename back in new table.

Comment: You're a beautiful person! Thank you!